# Method for evaluating $\int_{|z| = 1} \dfrac{z^2}{\sqrt[4]{P(z)}} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have a problem where I must evaluate

$$\int_{|z| = 1} \dfrac{z^2}{\sqrt[4]{P(z)}} dz$$

Where $P(z)$ is a polynomial with degree at least four and has exactly four roots in the unit circle. I know I am supposed to use the Cauchy-Goursat theorem and construct a contour  that avoids the discontinuities but I cannot imagine how to draw this contour or how to evaluate it.

Can I just draw any contour that avoids the singularities?

I would also appreciate any examples of contour integrals which include a fourth root in the denominator.

Comment: The Residue theorem seems to be what you are missing.

Comment: @MustafaSaid How do I use the residue theorem when I don't have isolated singularities?

Comment: Any two contours that are Homotopic to each other (within the region of analyticity) give rise to the same integral value. Hence, $$\int_C f = \int_{B(z_0,\epsilon)} f+\int_{B(z_1,\epsilon)} f+\int_{B(z_2,\epsilon)} f+\cdots$$ where $z_0,z_1,z_2,\ldots$ are the singularities of $f(z)$ inside of $C$. See for example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=op92K4Cv14o.